# Return span text from selected radio button using JQuery/JavaScript

Tags: jquery, html, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

I have a list of radio buttons of which only one can be checked. I would like to retrieve the  values from the selected radio button. I do not seem to  get any text in returned alert.

*Please note that this HTML is generated automatically and therefore I cannot edit it. Adding value to the  is therefore not possible.*

```
<form class="leaflet-control-layers-list">
<div class="leaflet-control-layers-base">
    <label>
        <input class="leaflet-control-layers-selector" type="radio" checked="checked" name="leaflet-base-layers"></input>
            <span>
                Gemeenten
            </span>
   </label>
   <label>
        <input class="leaflet-control-layers-selector" type="radio" name="leaflet-base-layers"></input>
            <span>
                Wijken
            </span>
   </label>
   <label>
       <input class="leaflet-control-layers-selector" type="radio" name="leaflet-base-layers"></input>
           <span>
               Buurten
           </span>
   </label>
</div>
</form>
```

This is the jQuery Script which I use:

```
radioButtonText = $('input[name=leaflet-base-layers].leaflet-control-layers-selector:checked').html();
alert(radioButtonText);
```

Does anybody know how I can return the text `Gemeenten´, ´Buurten´ or ´Wijken´ depending on which radio button is selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a value attribute in the input radio

```
<input value="Gemeenten" class="leaflet-control-layers-selector" type="radio" checked="checked" name="leaflet-base-layers">
```

And grab the radio input value using the .val() method

```
radioButtonText = $('input[name=leaflet-base-layers].leaflet-control-layers-selector:checked').val();
alert(radioButtonText);
```

And if you need the span html content:

```
radioButtonText = $('input[name=leaflet-base-layers].leaflet-control-layers-selector:checked');

var label_value = radioButtonText.closest('label').find('span').html();
alert(label_value);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I forgot to mention that this HTML code is generated automatically and therefore I cannot edit the HTML. This means I cannot give a value to the input.

Comment: Always glad to help, don't forget to mark the question as solved :)

Comment: I have a related question to this probem. Now I would like to do the reverse.Using the html value (gemeenten, wijken or buurten) as my starting point, I would like to check this radio button. Would you have any ideas how I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

Get the next html of the clicked radio button.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("input[type=radio]").click(function(e) {
        var inputs = $('input[type=radio]');
            alert($(this).next().html());

    });

});
```

Working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/5u94gzb8/

Answer (score 1):

*) Your selector is missing quotes around the item name.

*) You probably don't need the class ".leaflet-control-layers-selector" if you are using the button names.

*) You don't want .html() from the input, you want it from the following span which you can get using .next().

It should be:

```
radioButtonText = $('input[name="leaflet-base-layers"]:checked').next().html();
alert(radioButtonText);
```